# Mouse click navigation in vim tab

Tags: tabbed-user-interface, mouse

Now I navigate from one tab to another tab in Vim using the `gt` command, but it's little frustrating for me, because so far I've worked with editors that support mouse navigation.

Is there a way that I can control Vim with mouse?

Comment: Control+PageDown & PageUp do the same as `gt` and `gT` btw (also works from insert mode).

Comment: Sadly, this interferes with copying and pasting.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
:set mouse=a
```

I think you'll find the keys a bit faster though, if you take the time to learn them.

Comment: I had to double click on the tabs for neovim to switch.

Comment: In general I agree that the key commands are faster, but there are some operations that the mouse is better for: dragging to resize a window to the size you want is much easier than *guessing* that you want that window about 20 units larger, and typing `20 ctrl-w shift-+`

Comment: @xulfir lets just keep the answers to answering rather than recruiting or converting new acolytes.

Answer (score 3):

If you are specifically interested in movement in Vim, then you can add `set mouse=a` to your `~/.vimrc` file.